# How to set First login view controller before Home screen

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am using this [Link](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) for slide menu code..and it's successfully working but the problem is It redirects to the home screen first and I want to navigate first on login or register screen after that home screen with slide menu code.

```
   import UIKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    fileprivate func createMenuView() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! HomeViewController

    let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController

    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hex: "689F38")

    leftViewController.homeViewController = nvc

    let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(homeViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)

     slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
     slideMenuController.delegate = homeViewController
     self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
     self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
     self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

           self.createMenuView()

            return true
        }
```

Comment: Initially you have to show signUp and once user signUp use userdefaults to save boolean value true in signUpscreen.Now check user has signedUP or not .If user signedUp you have to show Homescreen if not you have to show sighUp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your loginViewController as  mainViewController

```
  let homeViewController = 
  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! 
  LoginViewController

  let leftViewController = 
  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftViewController") 
  as! LeftViewController

  let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: 
  mainViewController, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController, 
  rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
```